# Sessions on a remote cloud computer

Tags: php, curl, cloud

I am programming on a cloud platform called kodingen. I have an investing competition coming up and i am making an equation/algorithm to automatically trade for me. The way i am getting to do this (bearing in mind the trading site is in php/html) is by posting data to the site using curl extension for PHP. I want the function to update every 10 minutes and post the buy/sell commands to the site. The update function is not included. Why is this not working, has it got something to do with sessions and cookies not being able to be stored on a cloud computer.

```
function post_to_url($url, $data) {
$fields = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
   $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
}
rtrim($fields, '&');

$post = curl_init();

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($post);

curl_close($post);
}

 $data1 = array(
 "ifs-note" => "",
 "submitted" => 1,
 "confirmed" => 0,
 "ifs-quantity" => 100,
 "ticker" => "ADM:LN"
);
$data = array(
"loginsubmitted" => 1,
 "team-name" => "xxxxxxxxx",
"team-password" => "xxxxxxxxxx"
); 
$data2 = array(
"ifs-note" => "",
"submitted" => 0,
"confirmed" => 1,
"dis_ifs-quantity" => 100,
"ticker" => "ADM:LN",
"ifs-cost" => "1139.595"
);

post_to_url("https://www.studentinvestor.org/secure/login.php", $data);
post_to_url("http://www.studentinvestor.org/stock-buy.php", $data1);
post_to_url("http://www.studentinvestor.org/stock-buy.php", $data2);
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

I have tried with and without quotes around the numbers. Is there a better solution to doing the whole process e.g. ssh with python scripts on a remote computer?? 
Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

cURL does not store cookies by default, which probably logs you out of the site in between requests.

Examine the COOKIE* options of cURL in PHP

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
```